# Anyway to get a users Facebook ID from the fbsr_app-id cookie?

Tags: php, facebook

When someone visits my site via a facebook invite; is there anyway I can get their facebook user ID from the fbsr cookie?

eg:

[fbsr_235734256463063] => VWllUkB-HRAwgRSdggGNSwAIZ_-VIno11CBRVqZXeiB.qyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImNvZGUiOiJlY2JjY2EwZDgwOTg3NzAyNjQ4MWFhZjcuMS0xMDAwMDMxMTkxNDQ3MTN8SUlId19hanZxUUdOLWxfSFpuZXRhalpicGRVIiwiaXNzdWVkX2F0IjoxMzI2MjE0MzA0LCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiMTAwMDAzMTE5MTQ0NzEzIn0

Can I decrypt that lot with PHP, and get the users FB ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your application's cookie (in this case app_id=235734256463063) when you use the latest facebook library (Version 3.0+) the library will get the data from the signed_request cookie for you.

if you don't use the library use can find more data on how to parse the signed_request here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/